# How to change image to text using jquery's .hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseover, innerhtml

I need a simple script that allows me to change the inner html of a p tag which in my case is an image to just plain text when I hover over it.

Example:

```
<div id="one">
    <p><img src="events.png" alt="" /></p>
</div>
```

When i hover over the above p tag i want it to change to the text as seen below

```
<div id="one">
   <p>Events</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use javascript at all for this. This is handled very simply using css.

```
<div id="one">
    <p>
        <span>Events</span>
        <img src="events.png" alt="" />
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#one p>span{ display:none; }
#one p:hover span{ display:inline; }
#one p:hover img{ display:none; }
```

Here's a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/CKpCk/

Comment: IE6 says he does not like `>` in the CSS. (and `:hover` too)

Comment: IE6 is dead. > and :hover are well supported in IE7+. We are well past the point in time where we ever need to worry about IE6 support anymore, unless the OP specifically states the need for it to work with that bastard browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var html = $('#one p').html()

$('#one').hover(function(){
   $('p', this).html('Events');
}, function() {
   $('p', this).html(html);
})​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4utxS/)

Comment: Don't use javascript when css is what's called for.

Comment: I reckon I will ++1 you both `:)` have fun y'all!

Comment: @Geuis this is just a solution and if you can see, the question has been tagged with jQuery not CSS.

Comment: @Raminson yo yo, alright bruv! not well but kicking in! :) bit @ undefined health :P

Comment: While that's true @Raminson, it also seems clear that the dear fellow may not have been aware of a css solution to this problem. Its our responsibility, when we leave answers, to leave the *correct* answer for a problem, not just the one asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Try</title>
</head>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testHover").hover(function()
    {
         $("#testHover").html("Events");
    });
    });
    </script>
<body>
    <div id="one">

        <p style="width:200px;"id="testHover"><img src="events.jpg" alt="" /></p>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```